# With spring fox version 2.9.2 Im not able to access swagger

Tags: spring-boot, springfox

"Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors"

Comment: where is the question? add some error or give some detail

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I know this does not solve your problem directly, but consider moving to [springdoc](https://springdoc.org/). Springfox is so buggy at this point that is a pain to use. I've moved to `springdoc` 2 years ago because of its Spring WebFlux support and I am very happy about it. Additionally, it also supports Kotlin Coroutines, which I am not sure Springfox does.

If you decide to migrate, `springdoc` even has a [migration guide](https://springdoc.org/#migrating-from-springfox).

Comment: Thanks I shall look it